# Why can this substitution be made in Gabriel's Horn?

Tags: calculus

There's a bonus question on my homework that asks why the integral from

a to b sqrt(1+1/x^4)dx

is greater than the integral from

a to b (1dx).

I know they come close to each other but I can't seem to find a way to explain it in words. Any ideas?

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is increasing, maybe that's enough. To conclude that because $\frac{1}{x^4}>0$ we have $1+\frac{1}{x^4}>1$ and finally $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}>\sqrt{1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $1 + 1/x^4$ is always greater than $1$ because $1/x^4$ is positive.  Since that's greater than 1 we know $\sqrt{1 + 1/x^4} > 1$ so $\int_1^b \sqrt{1 + 1/x^4} dx > \int_a^b 1 dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}-1\gt0\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R},$$ 
$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}-1\right)dx\gt0$$
By linearity of the integral,
$$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}dx\gt\int_{a}^{b}dx.$$